# Failed to create ionic project?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

This Errors are occurring when I going to create a project.

> C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error
>           MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the
>            declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

```
 PS C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps> ionic start app blank
√ Creating directory .\app - done!
√ Downloading and extracting blank starter - done!

? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes
√ Personalizing ionic.config.json and package.json - done!
> ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet
√ Downloading integration cordova - done!
√ Copying integrations files to project - done!
[OK] Added cordova integration!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  *   IONIC  DEVAPP  *

 Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app

  -     Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
  -     LiveReload for instant style and JS updates

 ️-->    Install DevApp   <--

> npm i
× Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1):



        > node-sass@4.7.2 install C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass
        > node scripts/install.js

        Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-64_binding.node
        Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-64_binding.node":

        HTTP error 404 Not Found

        Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
               try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

               export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

        or configure npm proxy via

               npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

        > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
        > node lib/post_install.js


        > node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass
        > node scripts/build.js

        Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags=
        --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
        gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
        gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
        gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Tareque\\Desktop\\ionic apps\\app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
        gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
        gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
        gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
        gyp info using node@10.0.0 | win32 | x64
        gyp verb command rebuild []
        gyp verb command clean []
        gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
        gyp verb command configure []
        gyp verb check python checking for Python executable
        "C:\Users\Tareque\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" in the PATH
        gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Users\Tareque\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
        C:\Users\Tareque\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
        gyp verb check python version `C:\Users\Tareque\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -c "import
        platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "3.6.4\r\n"
        gyp verb could not find "C:\Users\Tareque\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe". checking python
        launcher
        gyp verb check python launcher python executable found: "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"
        gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"`
        returned: "2.7.15\r\n"
        gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 10.0.0
        gyp verb command install [ '10.0.0' ]
        gyp verb install input version string "10.0.0"
        gyp verb install installing version: 10.0.0
        gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
        gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
        gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
        gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
        gyp verb install version is good
        gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 10.0.0
        gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build
        gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build
        gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
        gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
        gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
        gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
        gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
        gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
        gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\Tareque\\Desktop\\ionic apps\\app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
        gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
        gyp info spawn args   '-f',
        gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
        gyp info spawn args   '-G',
        gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2013',
        gyp info spawn args   '-I',
        gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Tareque\\Desktop\\ionic
        apps\\app\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
        gyp info spawn args   '-I',
        gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Tareque\\Desktop\\ionic apps\\app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
        gyp info spawn args   '-I',
        gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Tareque\\.node-gyp\\10.0.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Tareque\\.node-gyp\\10.0.0',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\Tareque\\Desktop\\ionic apps\\app\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\Tareque\\.node-gyp\\10.0.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\Tareque\\Desktop\\ionic apps\\app\\node_modules\\node-sass',        gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
        gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
        gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
        gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
        gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\Tareque\\Desktop\\ionic apps\\app\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
        gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
        gyp verb command build []
        gyp verb build type Release
        gyp verb architecture x64
        gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\Tareque\.node-gyp\10.0.0
        gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
        gyp verb could not find "msbuild.exe" in PATH - finding location in registry
        gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
        gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
        gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
        gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
        Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
        Build started 5/8/2018 2:52:56 PM.
        Project "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" on node 1 (default
        targets).
        ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
           Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
        Project "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (1) is building
        "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) on node 1
        (default targets).
        Project "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) is
        building "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (3) on node
        1 (default targets).
        C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019:
        The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import>
        declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj"
        (default targets) -- FAILED.
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
        Done Building Project "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln"
        (default targets) -- FAILED.

        Build FAILED.

        "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
        "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target)
        (2) ->
        "C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (default target) (3)
        ->
           C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj(20,3): error
        MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the
        <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

             0 Warning(s)
             1 Error(s)

        Time Elapsed 00:00:00.63
        gyp ERR! build error
        gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic
        apps\app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:225:12)
        gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
        gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Tareque\\Desktop\\ionic
        apps\\app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
        "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
        gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Tareque\Desktop\ionic apps\app\node_modules\node-sass
        gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
        gyp ERR! not ok
        Build failed with error code: 1
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted
        {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tareque\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-08T08_52_57_968Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Can this help? https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1888

Comment: not working using that

Comment: or rebuild sass npm rebuild node-sass

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the environment variable many time after that errors start occurring.  Then I install python and set the environment variable and installed visual studio to resolve windows build error . Now it is working fine..